# multiple spinner+edittext to text view(android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, android-spinner

so im quite a beginner to android programming and im trying to do very basic stuff.I have 6 spinner with edit text(number) beside them, and I have a button. I need to,when button is clicked, to load a new page with a text view and display in the text view the content of spinner + edit text,for example:

spinner1:  blue  edittext: 3
spinner2: orange  edittext2: 9

would display

3: blue
9: orange

I dont know how to do that,do I need to create a new activity page or?and how to do that?ask if any code needed.

thank you

Comment: My understanding is that you have six Spinners and six TextView beside them, and one button also. You want that if you click on the button, second screen should open containing "Selected text of Spinners" and "Text of EditText".. Right???

Comment: yes,exactly.I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start learning from basic, there are many tutorials that will help you to learn basic things. Here I am giving you some ideas, I hope It will give you a good start.

At first you have to create two Activities and their layout (first one for user input and second for display).

**Layout of user input (layout_spinners.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnr_day"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnr_month"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Layout of display (layout_result.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity (SpinnerDemo.java)**

```
public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity {
String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday" };
String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May" };

Spinner daySpinner, monthSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> daysAdapter, monthAdapter;
EditText editText;
Button button;
String selectedDay, selectedMonth, text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_spinners);

    // Instantiating views
    daySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_day);
    monthSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_month);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    // Instantiating adapter
    daysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, days);
    monthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerDemo.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, months);

    // Setting adapter to Spinner
    daySpinner.setAdapter(daysAdapter);
    monthSpinner.setAdapter(monthAdapter);

    // OnClickListener of Button
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Getting values of text and spinners
            selectedDay = daySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            selectedMonth = monthSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            text = editText.getText().toString();

            // Creating an Intent to open new Activity(Screen) and sending
            // the details
            Intent intent = new Intent(SpinnerDemo.this, Results.class);
            intent.putExtra("day", selectedDay);
            intent.putExtra("month", selectedMonth);
            intent.putExtra("text", text);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

}
```

**Activity (Results.java)**

```
public class Results extends Activity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_result);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        String day = intent.getStringExtra("day");
        String month = intent.getStringExtra("month");
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

        textView.setText(day + "\n" + month + "\n" + text);

    }
    else
    {
        textView.setText("Intent is null");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: first of all,thanks a lot for your help.However, I pasted your code (no errors) but when I try to launch your project on a virtual device, it crash? whats the problem? thanks

Comment: Most Welcome.. Johnny_b.. Did you add activities to application's manifest file? Don't forget to add all activities in manifest file. If you are using eclipse ADT see LogCat for corresponding errors and post that errors here..

Comment: Ok so I managed to finally make it works.thanks! however, how I am supposed to do this if,for my original code, my spinner items are defined in valuesin a XML files? my items are in a array in a xml files so how do I adapt this?thank you

Comment: and I populate my spinner with xml file like this : android:entries="@array/Type(wich is the array containing items)" />